# Blackout backup

Tags: backup

I have Ubuntu 20.10. For some days, I have to work my PC without any backup-battery-stuff for blackout. Please advise me about backup tools, if any. For, regretfully, blackouts are commonplace in our district.
However, if Ubuntu 20.10 is strong enough to withstand blackout (a wrong shut down) without any special backup installed, kindly let me know.
Thanks.

Comment: Are you talking about a UPS?

Comment: If you mean "uninterruptible power supplier", I have never seen one but on the Internet.

Comment: What kind of backup are you asking for? What kind of computer do you have? I think you should [edit] your question to explain as good as possible what solution you're looking for :) If you're not good at english, feel free to explain in the comments, and I (or others) will add it into the question :)

Comment: Let me try to explain. You work on your PC. Several important windows opened on the Internet and PC. Now, imagine that you have got blackout (electricity gone) and there is no any accumulator between PC & the wall socket to keep electric power on for some minutes, so that you can save your work and close all windows one by one.

Comment: You're looking for a UPS. It's essentially a battery that provides a buffer. The capacity depends on your needs - you can get small UPSes that will supply a single computer for a few minutes - long enough to save your work and power down, up to UPSes that can run a datacenter for an hour. A cheap UPS will generally be in the area of ~100USD.

Comment: Thank you. I agree with you 100%. But the question is what to do when that UPS stuff is absent for some days? Can Ubuntu save my files?

Comment: Without a UPS there is nothing you can do. Even if you did constant backing up to a network server that would not be affected by the blackout, you can do it at most each time your files are changed/written. And you will have that same state on your own machine once the power comes back, as long as you use a modern, journaling file system such as ext4.

Comment: Your best choice is to get a UPS. They're not very expensive for a basic unit. Your next best choice is to use software that automatically saves. LibreOffice and Sublime Text come to mind, though many text editors have the ability to autosave. If you're entering text into a browser window, there are extensions like [this one](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/autosave-text/omgpghebcjlafeegihofjnhhmllplnie) that you can use. But, a UPS is absolutely going to be your best option. They're available for under $100 USD with adequate time to do a proper save and shutdown.

Answer (score 0):

I use [fwbackups](http://www.diffingo.com/oss/fwbackups/download). But here are more backup tool solutions: [Comparison of backup tools](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2596/comparison-of-backup-tools/1292497#1292497).

Comment: I tried. Terminal answered "unable".

Comment: I don't understand what you mean with terminal answered "unable".